# How do you delete duplicate records in MySQL with certain conditions?

Tags: mysql

Suppose you have a MySQL table that contains a timestamp column.  Is there an **efficient** query I can run that would eliminate rows where information is identical in the non-timestamp columns *except* it would return the first and last timestamp for each of these groups?

So for example, running the query on the following table:

```
|    A    |    B    |  timestamp |
----------------------------------
|    a    |    b    |      1     |
|    a    |    b    |      2     |
|    a    |    b    |      3     |
|    a    |    b    |      4     |
|    a    |    b    |      5     |
|    c    |    d    |      3     |
|    c    |    d    |      4     |
|    c    |    d    |      5     |
|    c    |    d    |      6     |
|    e    |    f    |      1     |
|    e    |    f    |      2     |
|    e    |    f    |      3     |
```

Would yield:

```
|    A    |    B    |  timestamp |
----------------------------------
|    a    |    b    |      1     |
|    a    |    b    |      5     |
|    c    |    d    |      3     |
|    c    |    d    |      6     |
|    e    |    f    |      1     |
|    e    |    f    |      3     |
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is mysql version

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below way -

```
select * from tablename t
where 
timestamp=(select min(timestamp) from tablename t1 where t.A=t1.A and t.B=t1.B)
or 
timestamp=(select max(timestamp) from tablename t1 where t.A=t1.A and t.B=t1.B)
```